# What method gets called when iPhone app exits?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I know that -applicationWillResignActive gets called upon an incoming call, but is there a standard method that gets called if the user hits the "exit" button (the only button on the front of the iPhone)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application`, in UIApplicationDelegate protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I made some try and i'm using iPhone SDK 4, and when you press the "exit" button the app called two methods:

```
(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```